Angular ShadowDOM encapsulation of JavaScript
I'm trying to encapsulate an angular application into a classical CMS website. For styles the encapsulation works fine. However, as both (the CMS website as well as the Angular app) use bootstrap with popper.js my nav-component in the CMS breaks. This is because the CMS tries to execute code inside my shadow root.
Is there any way to prevent this?
Specifically, this part of the code is excecuted, which I would like to avoid as there is also a popper.js version in the parent CMS.
// node_modules/@popperjs/core/lib/dom-utils/getComputedStyle.js
function getComputedStyle(element) {
  return getWindow(element).getComputedStyle(element);
}

Thanks in advance!
